# IEEE-754 Format Conversion

Tags: arithmetic, binary, floating-point

Represent $11.0011*2^{10}$ using the
IEEE-$754$ standard for $32$-bit floating point
representation.

$0$-Sign Bit
$10001010-$Exponent
$1001100000000000000000$-Mantissa

Is this answer is correct ? I am bit confused .. Please Help

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/305901) might help.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Use [this](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to find the correct representation.

Comment: @achillehui       is the answer given by "gammatester" is correct ? Plz Help

Comment: @HimanshuChawla If $11.0011$ really mean a number in base $2$ (It is not clear in your question), then gammatester answer is the one you want.

Comment: But if $11.0011$ is in binary, who is to say what the exponent $10$ means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct, you only missed a $0$ in the mantissa. Your number is $1.10011_2\times 2^{11}=3264_{10}$. The sign bit is $0$ the **biased** exponent is $11+127=138= 10001010_2$ and the mantissa without the implied leading bit is $10011000000000000000000_2$. 
Concatenated this gives
$$11.0011_2\times 2^{10} \rightarrow01000101010011000000000000000000_2\\ 
= 0100\_0101\_0100\_1100\_0000\_0000\_0000\_0000_2 =454C0000_{16}$$
Check it e.g. with http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html

Comment: Thank You @gammatester for giving the answer .... I m very thankful to you.